# Printing the address of function... declaration?

Tags: c++

Consider the following MCVE:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    void foo(int);
    std::cout << foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here I intentionally try to print a pointer to a function in a wrong way so that the [operator<< overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) which accepts `bool` is chosen.

```
 basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );
```

The thing that puzzles me is that both [gcc 7.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yIMnYX1RMOpWcc9T) and [clang 5.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/x2J4mTt9g5MoKpWv) produce a warning, but compile and *link* the program.

In the same time, *Visual Studio 15.5.6* doesn't link this example.

Personally, I expected, that this code won't link at all despite the compiler used as `foo` seems to be *ODR-used*.

Could anybody explain why *gcc* and *clang* are able to link the program?

Comment: If you don't provide the function then it's undefined behaviour.  The compiler is allowed to assume UB never happens.  I could see this chain of "logic" allowing the compiler to just output "true" and ignore the function completely .

Comment: Sounds like a compiler-dependent extension that adds a `function pointer to boolean` conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an ODR violation. But according to [[basic.def.odr]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10), emphasis mine:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a
>   discarded statement; **no diagnostic required**. The definition can
>   appear explicitly in the program, it can be found in the standard or a
>   user-defined library, or (when appropriate) it is implicitly defined
>   (see [class.ctor], [class.dtor] and [class.copy]). An inline function
>   or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is
>   odr-used outside of a discarded statement.

And we must recall that compilers are free to assume you don't write code that exhibits undefined behavior or is otherwise ill-formed in ways they don't need to diagnose. Because each function must have an address that isn't null, the `bool` overload can just be called with `true`, since that's what the conversion must yield in a *valid program*.

We can see [GCC 7.3](https://godbolt.org/g/5qDT5x) doing just that. It passes 1 for what is meant to be the result of the conversion, even at `-O0`.

Comment: Aha, makes sense now!